Getting a 404 Not found for OpenIddict even if "The token request was successfully validated."
I am attempting to use OpenIddict to set up a client credentials flow using
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseOpenIddict();
}

services.AddOpenIddict()
        .AddCore(options =>
        {
           options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                  .UseDbContext<MyDbContext>();
        })
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
           options
               .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

           options
               .AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

           options
               .AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
               .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

           options
               .UseAspNetCore()
           .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
        });

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
   {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Identity.Application";
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Identity.Application";
       options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Identity.Application";
   });

services.AddAuthentication();
services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddRouting();
services.AddControllers();

When I invoke the token endpoint /connect/token with the following client credentials (which are correct)

I get a 404 error message

Even if the backend was able to successfully validate the credentials

Can someone point in the correct direction? I have been pulling my hair out the entire day.

To address the 404 Not Found error when using OpenIddict for a client credentials flow, ensure that routing is correctly configured, middleware is in the right order, and the /connect/token endpoint is properly registered. Verify that you have the necessary OpenIddict ASP.NET Core integration package installed and configured in the ConfigureServices method. Double-check the endpoint URL and ensure that client credentials are correctly registered in the database and that development certificates are properly generated and used.

I am facing same issues. Any response on this, please?

anyone update solution ?  i'm facing same issue.
